# dual-stack static setup won't stay configured in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ipv6

I have a media server (plex) configured on a VM on my home network. It is dual stack with static ipv4 and ipv6 addresses. After upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04, the manual configuration broke and I lost my static ipv6 gateway route. I have the following set in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.9
    netmask 255.255.255.128
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2001:***:e3a7::9
    netmask 64
    gateway 2001:***:e3a7::1
    dns-nameservers 2001:***:8:c23::108
```

This worked fine under 14.04. Under 16.04, the static gateway does nothing. After a fresh reboot, I get the following:

```
default via fe80::226:88ff:fee8:7600 dev eth0
```

So at least I know it's seeing the RAs on the segment (all the other devices doing straight SLAAC seem fine). I turned off autoconf vi sysctl and explicitly turned ON accept_ra. Somehow, 30 seconds after boot, something turns it off:

```
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra = 0
```

I would love to know why I can't simply put a static ipv6 setup in a supposed "server" OS and what the *(&^* is changing my sysctl variables after I've already booted, making me loose my ipv6 routing.

Dan

Comment: Upon further investigation, it appears that as long as I specify a "gateway" statement in my inet6 configuration, something turns off my sysctl value above. If I comment out the gateway line, the static interface comes up and default routing is obtained by the RAs.

If I set a static gateway, I have my ability to learn RAs disabled for me and the static is also somehow pulled after about a minute (neighbor timeout?).

Is there something implemented in the 16.04 network stack to disallow static routing in a network where my RAs are sending only "onlink" and "auto" flags?